# Finding Semantic Coherence between sentences in a text

Tags: python, vector, tf-idf, sentence-similarity, latent-semantic-analysis

I need some help writing a program based on the code from these links [link1](http://blog.josephwilk.net/projects/latent-semantic-analysis-in-python.html) and [link2](http://blog.josephwilk.net/projects/building-a-vector-space-search-engine-in-python.html) that will automatically calculate the semantic similarity between a. Consecutive sentences and b. Sentences seperates by 1 intervening phrase, in and entire document (1000 sentences).

The provided code already tokenizes and can find semantic similarity but I have no clue how to write the new code that will calculate (and display) the semantic similarity between consecutive and "intervening" sentences across the whole text (a,b).I don't want to do the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Have you looked at [word2vec](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf)  ([or this](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/04/21/the-amazing-power-of-word-vectors/)) at all? I've used its python implementation for something similar in the past.

Comment: Hello, these articles are mostly theory which I understand, I am having trouble with applting the ideas into code and automating the process.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I imagine you would have some kind of program that reads files in line by line and compares them to the next line /  adjacent phrase?

Comment: Hi I've found this [link](https://github.com/sujitpal/nltk-examples/blob/master/src/semantic/short_sentence_similarity.py), which I think does the task for consecutive sentences (please correct me if I'm wrong and misunderstanding the code). If not how would you change this code for non consecutive phrases?

Comment: The similarity function in the last link you provided would let you compare semantic similarity between sentences, you would have to have a feeder program that loops over the sentences you wanted to compare.

Comment: I see, any ideas on how to write something that can achieve that and implement it in the code provided by the link? I apologize for the questions I am a linguistics professor and this is my first foray into python. I do not usually deal in comp. Sci.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want, adjust it depending on how you want the output formatted.

```
with open("sentence_file_name", "r") as sentence_file:
    while x and y:
    x = sentence_file.readline()
    y = sentence_file.readline()
    similarity(x, y, boolean) #boolean set to false or true depending on what you want
    x = y
    y = sentence_file.readline()
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but where would you implement this in the code provided in the link?

Comment: Copy/fork everything from line 1-245, then add the above code below that. Replace sentence_file_name with whatever the relative path of your sentence file is. This isn't technically the clean way to do this, but would probably be the simplest.